# Подсчитать и вывести количество строк в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql, сортировка

**ВСЕМ ПРИВЕТ!**

Помогите справиться с задачкой. Есть таблица metki нужно вывести число на страницу сколько всего значений в таблице у которых в столбце type значение orange

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть чтобы получилось что при сортировки были выбраны только те данные у которых значение type будет orange

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и на странице рhp вывести число найденных значений с type = orange
в данном примере 2

```
SELECT * FROM `metki` WHERE `type` = 'orange'

<h1><?php echo ........ ?></h1>
<span>Общее количество оранжевых</span>
```

Comment: У БД есть отличная функция, count() которая возвращает уже готовое количество. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Counting_rows.html

Answer (score 0):

Для подсчета строк в базе данных служит функция [count()](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Counting_rows.html).

Для работы с базой данных в РНР надо использовать PDO.

Соответственно, если тип всегда будет "orange" (или вообще без условий - в общем, в любом случае, когда в запросе не используются переменые), то использовать метод `query()`:

```
$count = $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM `metki` WHERE `type` = 'orange'")->fetchColumn();
```

А если тип может меняться, или в любых других случаях когда в запросе используются переменные, то использовать надо [подготовленные запросы](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#prepare):

```
$type = 'orange';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM `metki` WHERE `type` = ?"); 
$stmt->execute([$type]); 
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

здесь мы сначала подготавливаем запрос, передавая вместо всех переменных знак вопроса, затем выполняем его, передавая все переменные в виде массива, а затем получаем результат.